# Darken image in div on hover, but not another child image

Tags: css, hover

On hover, I'm trying to change the opacity of the main parent to darken the main image, but I want to show another image over it in full opacity. Here's what I tried, but it's not working.

```
  <div class="masonry-item">
  <div class="masonry-item1">

    <a href="#" class="image">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><img src="blah" /></h3> <!-- DARKEN THIS -->
      </div>
       <img src="blah" /> <!-- KEEP FULL OPACITY -->
     </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

my css:

```
  .masonry-container .masonry-item .image:hover .caption {
   opacity: 1;

  }

 .masonry-container .masonry-item a.image:hover img {
  opacity: .2; /* this seems to darken everything, but when removed darkening doesn't work */

 }

 .masonry-container .masonry-item1:hover {
   background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.5);
   z-index:98;
 }
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
http://screencast.com/t/7qDUmCJMNd

Comment: Add a JS fiddle demonstrating the issue please. And while at it - remove those ancient `filter` stuff - IE8- is really dead these days. Same goes for `-webkit-transition` - it's been [unprefixed for ages now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Comment: and also some of the css vs markup is different in some way, you have 'a.image:hover' on your css, but no 'a' tags in your markup, or '.image' class on any tag

Comment: sorry guys, I updated the code. I messed up while bringing it into stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjc0qvk3/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="masonry-item">
    <div class="masonry-item1">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><img id="image1" src="http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" /></h3> <!-- DARKEN THIS -->
        </div>
        <img id="image2" src="http://laurafranksblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" /> <!-- KEEP FULL OPACITY -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masonry-item1 {
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
.masonry-item1:hover #image1 {
    opacity: .2;
    transition: all 1s;
}

/* This is just to get the images to overlap, you don't need this if you're doing it another way */
#image1, #image2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Although there is no darken, I believe you could make it as @mikelt21's answer.

```
<div class="masonry-item">
    <img id="i1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-and-finance-9/250/vector_265_07-01-128.png" />
    <img id="i2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-and-finance-9/250/vector_265_20-01-128.png" />
</div>

<style>
img{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover #i1{
    opacity:1;
}
div:hover #i2{
    opacity:0;
}
#i1{
    opacity:0;
}
#i1:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

[Here is the example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/25pzub6m/1/)